# Manual or Auto installation for Magento in cPanel?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-enterprise, installation

I am looking for the best option for magento **(ce and enterprise)** installation on cpanel.

Which one is better, and why?

Automatic installation through softaculous or whatever?
or
Manual installation?

Comment: Automatic installation  is best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic installation is simple and quick. According to my experience: Manual installation is best as you have full control to choose version,sample data installation option, database etc. It makes everything in your control though this process may take some time to upload and installation.

Have a close look at manual installation give you more details of modules installing and database tables as well